# Inserting into a JavaScript object inside razor foreach?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

While I loop through a C# list in a partial view, I need to add to JavaScript object, I tried `<text></text>` and `@:` but they just render the plain JavaScript text, here's the full partial-view:

```
@using Resources;
<script>
    var resources = {};
@{
    Dictionary<string, string> resx = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var item in typeof(AppResources).GetProperties().Where(p=>p.PropertyType==typeof(string)))
    {
        resx.Add(item.Name, item.GetValue(item).ToString());
        var key = item.Name;
        var value = item.GetValue(item).ToString();
        @:resources[@key] = @value;
    }
}
    console.log("resources_BEGIN");
    console.log(resources);
    console.log("resources_END");

</script>
```

this is being rendered in the HTML source:

```
<script>
    var resources = {};
    resources[lbAccountSettings] = Account settings;
    resources[lbActivate] = Activate;
    resources[lbArabicName] = Arabic Name;
    resources[lbAreas] = Areas;
    console.log("resources_BEGIN");
    console.log(resources);
    console.log("resources_END");
</script>
```

Comment: So the desired HTML source should be like this: `resources['lbAccountSettings'] = 'Account settings';` ... etc?

Comment: @Ammar well, this isn't meant to be an HTML at all, I used this workaround to be able to use razor with JS, so I don't need to render it as HTML, all I need is to make an assignment to the JS object.

Comment: I know that you want to make an assignment to JS object, but I mean, the desired JS statements should be like `resources['lbAccountSettings'] = 'Account settings'; resources['lbActivate'] = 'Activate';`? maybe `@Html.Raw($"resources['{key}'] = '{value}';")` will solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `var jsvariable=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(<your_charp_variable>))`

**Edited**:

```
<script>
 var resources = {}
    @{ 
        Dictionary<string, string> resx = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (var item in typeof(AppResource).GetProperties().Where(p=>p.PropertyType==typeof(string)))
        {
            resx.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
    resources=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(resx));
</script>
```

Comment: A working answer is respected, I don't have an idea what to put instead `<your_charp_variable>`

Comment: If I understand your question, I will put the ```resx``` variable to the ```Json.Encode()``` function, after the ```foreach``` loop ended.

Comment: I need to do an assignment to JavaScript variable `resources`